# Блок, плывущий за прокруткой страницы

Tags: css3, html, css

Как сделать блок, который при прокручивании страницы вниз "плывет за ней"? Желательно, средствами CSS.

Пример: На главной странице Хабрахабра блок "Лучшее" в правой колонке появляется при прокрутке страницы вниз, если справа есть свободное место.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, Вы имеете ввиду `position: fixed`?

[Пример с fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/po4teda/VBLfC/).

Тогда блок будет всегда в указанном месте и будет следовать прокрутке, однако, плавного эффекта Вы получить не сможете. Здесь Вам сможет помочь JavaScript, который обрабатывает события прокрутки.